# What is the accepted 'elegant' solution for parsing URL strings to select a response function in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty

Question is,

**What is the accepted 'elegant' solution for parsing URL strings to select a response function in Jetty?**

I've provided some background, but feel free to skip my waffle!

---

The situation is that I've written a bunch of client/server code in Java, using a socket connection to communicate serialized Java objects. Obviously, this depended on both the client and server being in Java, and while that was fine to start with I wish to make the system more universal and resilient to firewalls.

Therefore, I've decided to create a REST API to communicate the data over HTTP. 
I DON'T want to produce any HTML - all responses will be JSON-encoded. Therefore, I'd rather not create individual files for each response - instead, I'd like to redirect each HTTP request, based on its type and URL, to a Java method which will produce a JSON response.
Unfortunately my only experience of programming servers is using Python/Django, and I'd rather not change language at this point.

So my question is very simple - how do I set up an embedded Jetty server to parse URLs? I've tried reading the docs, but had trouble making sense of this. At the moment, it seems there are two possibilities.

One is the *target* string in the *handle* method of the *AbstractHandler* [javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler.html), which I believe contains the entire URL string? So I could manually parse this in a Java method, to which all web requests would be directed.

The other is to use a chain of ContextServletHandler? Not precisely sure how that would be done, or whether this is the intended use of that function.*

Comment: not that I don't want to support usage of jetty as more then a servlet engine, but is there a reason you don't want to use servlets and simply tap into a project like jersey for building your rest api?  most of the work is done at that point

Comment: um... i guess to avoid restructuring more code... why would jersey be better?